# get coordinates of z point

Tags: c, matrix

I'm working on an optimization problem. I have to traverse a 2D matrix using a [z-order curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve). So I should just get the x and y coordinates correspondent to a counter variable.
One way is of course just using for loops to [look at the bits of the counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve#/media/File:Zcurve45bits.png) but it's way too slow.
[Here](https://www.forceflow.be/2013/10/07/morton-encodingdecoding-through-bit-interleaving-implementations/) there are fast implementations but they're made to get the z value (so the 'counter' value) of a coordinate tuple.
Are there similar ways to do the other way around? From z to (x,y)? Or can I somehow use the previously linked resource for my goal with some workarounds?

The language I'm using is C.

Comment: You have a Morton encoder and want a decoder? Making a look-up table should be easy enough. Also why the `caching` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you link for implementations deals with 3D encoding. If I understand your question correctly, you want a 2D Morton decoder.

Here is a simple encoder/decoder pair for 16-bit coordinates (relatively easy to extend to 32-bits, either with a 128-bit type or with double the computations).

```
typedef struct xy16 {
    uint16_t x;
    uint16_t y;
} xy16;

uint32_t morton_encode(xy16 xy) {
    uint64_t result = xy.x | ((uint64_t)xy.y << 32);
    result |= (result << 8);
    result &= 0x00ff00ff00ff00ff;
    result |= (result << 4);
    result &= 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f;
    result |= (result << 2);
    result &= 0x3333333333333333;
    result |= (result << 1);
    result &= 0x5555555555555555;
    return (uint32_t)result | (result >> 31);
}

xy16 morton_decode(uint32_t morton) {
    uint64_t result = morton | ((uint64_t)morton << 31);
    result &= 0x5555555555555555;
    result |= (result >> 1);
    result &= 0x3333333333333333;
    result |= (result >> 2);
    result &= 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f;
    result |= (result >> 4);
    result &= 0x00ff00ff00ff00ff;
    result |= (result >> 8);
    xy16 xy = {(uint16_t)result, (uint16_t)(result >> 32)};
    return xy;
}
```

And here is a look-up table version.

```
xy16 morton_decode_lut(uint32_t morton) {
    static const uint8_t lut_x[] = {
        0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x2, 0x3, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x2, 0x3,
        0x4, 0x5, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x6, 0x7, 0x4, 0x5, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x6, 0x7,
        0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x2, 0x3, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x2, 0x3,
        0x4, 0x5, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x6, 0x7, 0x4, 0x5, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x6, 0x7,
        0x8, 0x9, 0x8, 0x9, 0xa, 0xb, 0xa, 0xb, 0x8, 0x9, 0x8, 0x9, 0xa, 0xb, 0xa, 0xb,
        0xc, 0xd, 0xc, 0xd, 0xe, 0xf, 0xe, 0xf, 0xc, 0xd, 0xc, 0xd, 0xe, 0xf, 0xe, 0xf,
        0x8, 0x9, 0x8, 0x9, 0xa, 0xb, 0xa, 0xb, 0x8, 0x9, 0x8, 0x9, 0xa, 0xb, 0xa, 0xb,
        0xc, 0xd, 0xc, 0xd, 0xe, 0xf, 0xe, 0xf, 0xc, 0xd, 0xc, 0xd, 0xe, 0xf, 0xe, 0xf,
        0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x2, 0x3, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x2, 0x3,
        0x4, 0x5, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x6, 0x7, 0x4, 0x5, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x6, 0x7,
        0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x2, 0x3, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x2, 0x3,
        0x4, 0x5, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x6, 0x7, 0x4, 0x5, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x6, 0x7,
        0x8, 0x9, 0x8, 0x9, 0xa, 0xb, 0xa, 0xb, 0x8, 0x9, 0x8, 0x9, 0xa, 0xb, 0xa, 0xb,
        0xc, 0xd, 0xc, 0xd, 0xe, 0xf, 0xe, 0xf, 0xc, 0xd, 0xc, 0xd, 0xe, 0xf, 0xe, 0xf,
        0x8, 0x9, 0x8, 0x9, 0xa, 0xb, 0xa, 0xb, 0x8, 0x9, 0x8, 0x9, 0xa, 0xb, 0xa, 0xb,
        0xc, 0xd, 0xc, 0xd, 0xe, 0xf, 0xe, 0xf, 0xc, 0xd, 0xc, 0xd, 0xe, 0xf, 0xe, 0xf
    };

    static const uint8_t lut_y[] = {
        0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x2, 0x2, 0x3, 0x3, 0x2, 0x2, 0x3, 0x3,
        0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x2, 0x2, 0x3, 0x3, 0x2, 0x2, 0x3, 0x3,
        0x4, 0x4, 0x5, 0x5, 0x4, 0x4, 0x5, 0x5, 0x6, 0x6, 0x7, 0x7, 0x6, 0x6, 0x7, 0x7,
        0x4, 0x4, 0x5, 0x5, 0x4, 0x4, 0x5, 0x5, 0x6, 0x6, 0x7, 0x7, 0x6, 0x6, 0x7, 0x7,
        0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x2, 0x2, 0x3, 0x3, 0x2, 0x2, 0x3, 0x3,
        0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x2, 0x2, 0x3, 0x3, 0x2, 0x2, 0x3, 0x3,
        0x4, 0x4, 0x5, 0x5, 0x4, 0x4, 0x5, 0x5, 0x6, 0x6, 0x7, 0x7, 0x6, 0x6, 0x7, 0x7,
        0x4, 0x4, 0x5, 0x5, 0x4, 0x4, 0x5, 0x5, 0x6, 0x6, 0x7, 0x7, 0x6, 0x6, 0x7, 0x7,
        0x8, 0x8, 0x9, 0x9, 0x8, 0x8, 0x9, 0x9, 0xa, 0xa, 0xb, 0xb, 0xa, 0xa, 0xb, 0xb,
        0x8, 0x8, 0x9, 0x9, 0x8, 0x8, 0x9, 0x9, 0xa, 0xa, 0xb, 0xb, 0xa, 0xa, 0xb, 0xb,
        0xc, 0xc, 0xd, 0xd, 0xc, 0xc, 0xd, 0xd, 0xe, 0xe, 0xf, 0xf, 0xe, 0xe, 0xf, 0xf,
        0xc, 0xc, 0xd, 0xd, 0xc, 0xc, 0xd, 0xd, 0xe, 0xe, 0xf, 0xf, 0xe, 0xe, 0xf, 0xf,
        0x8, 0x8, 0x9, 0x9, 0x8, 0x8, 0x9, 0x9, 0xa, 0xa, 0xb, 0xb, 0xa, 0xa, 0xb, 0xb,
        0x8, 0x8, 0x9, 0x9, 0x8, 0x8, 0x9, 0x9, 0xa, 0xa, 0xb, 0xb, 0xa, 0xa, 0xb, 0xb,
        0xc, 0xc, 0xd, 0xd, 0xc, 0xc, 0xd, 0xd, 0xe, 0xe, 0xf, 0xf, 0xe, 0xe, 0xf, 0xf,
        0xc, 0xc, 0xd, 0xd, 0xc, 0xc, 0xd, 0xd, 0xe, 0xe, 0xf, 0xf, 0xe, 0xe, 0xf, 0xf
    };

    xy16 xy;
    xy.x = lut_x[(morton >> 24) & 0xff];
    xy.y = lut_y[(morton >> 24) & 0xff];
    xy.x = xy.x << 4;
    xy.y = xy.y << 4;
    xy.x |= lut_x[(morton >> 16) & 0xff];
    xy.y |= lut_y[(morton >> 16) & 0xff];
    xy.x = xy.x << 4;
    xy.y = xy.y << 4;
    xy.x |= lut_x[(morton >> 8) & 0xff];
    xy.y |= lut_y[(morton >> 8) & 0xff];
    xy.x = xy.x << 4;
    xy.y = xy.y << 4;
    xy.x |= lut_x[morton & 0xff];
    xy.y |= lut_y[morton & 0xff];
    return xy;
}
```

I'm not sure which would be the fastest. The look-up tables can easily be extended to 2^16 = 65536 values to save 4 look-ups and shifts. I generated them by simply printing the values I get from the simpler `morton_decode` above. The same can be done to make a look-up table version of the encoder.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ahqPoa3eT)